# Finding $E(XY)$ given $E(X)$, $E(Y)$, $E(Y^2)$, $E(X|Y)$

Tags: probability, covariance, conditional-expectation

So here is what I know:
\begin{align}
E(X) &= 13\\
E(Y) &= 2\\
E(X|Y) &= 3y + 7\\
E(Y^2) &= 8
\end{align}
How do I find $E(XY)$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
E[XY] & =E[E[XY|Y]]
\\ & =E[E[X|Y]\cdot Y]
\\ & =E[(3Y+7)\cdot Y]
\\ & =E[3Y^2+7Y]
\\ & =3E[Y^2]+7E[Y]
\\ & =3\cdot 8 +7\cdot 2
\\ & =24+14
\\ &=38 
\end{align}$$